# Moving circle flashing in applet

Tags: java, swing, animation, applet

I have created an applet with a red circle to move from top left to bottom right.  That occurs but the whole frame is flickering even though I generate the circle as a buffered image.  Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;  
import java.awt.Graphics;  
import java.awt.Image;  
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;  
import javax.swing.JApplet;  

public class MovingCircleApplet extends JApplet implements Runnable {

private int x_pos;
private int y_pos;
private int radius;
private Thread circle;

@Override
public void init() {
    x_pos  = 20;
    y_pos  = 40;
    radius = 10;
    setSize(245,265);
    circle = new Thread(this);
    circle.start();
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        // redraw
        repaint();

        try
        {
            // sleep thread for 20 milliseconds
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Terminated prematurely due to interruption");
        }

        // move circle to lower right corner
        if (x_pos < 225) 
        {
            x_pos++;
            y_pos++;
        }
        // restart at top right corner
        else 
        {
            x_pos = 20;
            y_pos = 40;
        }           
    }
}  
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(getFrame(), 0, 0, null);
}

private Image getFrame() 
{
    // Buffered image to prevent flickering
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(),getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
    // white background
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    // red circle
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(x_pos-radius, y_pos-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
    //
    g.dispose();
    return img;
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) The best way to do painting in Swing is to start a `javax.swing.Timer` that calls `repaint()` 3) `g.drawImage(getFrame(), 0, 0, null);` should instead be `g.drawImage(getFrame(), 0, 0, this);`..

Comment: I am required to write this as an applet.  I am not clear from the comment above exactly how I should modify my applet to make it work.  I changed "null" to "this" in the drawImage method call and it didn't change anything.  The screen still flickers.

Comment: *"I am required to write this as an applet."*  Required by who? ..By your teacher?  *"I am not clear from the comment above exactly how I should modify my applet to make it work."*  I'm not sure that's a question, in fact, I'm pretty sure it is not.  But then, don't expect to be spoon fed on SO.  Try something (at the very least plug 'animation swing timer' into your favorite search engine and see what pops out). *"I changed "null" to "this" in the drawImage method call and it didn't change anything."* It only changes something if the images are loaded asynchronously.  We should not assume...

Comment: Was allowed to write it as a JFrame application and had no problems.